# Mongoid + MongoHQ + Heroku error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, mongoid, mongohq

HI this is my first time deploying an app on heroku using mongoid + mongoHQ

i manage to push to heroku but my app has an error, i checked heroku logs and this is what
it shows

```
    2012-12-02T05:36:43+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
2012-12-02T05:36:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered home/_store_search.html.erb (1.4ms)
2012-12-02T05:36:43+00:00 app[web.1]:     7: 
2012-12-02T05:36:43+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:        <div class="store">
2012-12-02T05:36:43+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-12-02T05:36:43+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-12-02T05:36:43+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
2012-12-02T05:36:43+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:    <h4 align="center">Best of Yelp Stores </h4>
2012-12-02T05:36:43+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=evening-bayou-5137.herokuapp.com fwd=128.54.34.17 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=1ms service=332ms status=500 bytes=643
2012-12-02T05:36:43+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:           
2012-12-02T05:36:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (102.9ms)
2012-12-02T05:36:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/home/index.html.erb:8:in `sort_by'
2012-12-02T05:36:43+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-12-02T05:36:43+00:00 app[web.1]:     5: 
2012-12-02T05:36:43+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 180ms
2012-12-02T05:36:43+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:    <% @stores.sort_by{ |store| store.avg_rating || 0}.reverse.each.with_index do |store, index| %>
2012-12-02T05:36:43+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:           
2012-12-02T05:36:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/home/index.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_home_index_html_erb__1734857390086193972_44325160'
2012-12-02T05:36:44+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=evening-bayou-5137.herokuapp.com fwd=128.54.34.17 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=0ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=0
2012-12-02T05:41:38+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails console` by jsabilla@ucsd.edu
2012-12-02T05:41:45+00:00 heroku[run.9005]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails console`
2012-12-02T05:41:45+00:00 heroku[run.9005]: Awaiting client
2012-12-02T05:41:45+00:00 heroku[run.9005]: State changed from starting to up
2012-12-02T05:46:25+00:00 heroku[run.9005]: Client connection closed. Sending SIGHUP to all processes
2012-12-02T05:46:26+00:00 heroku[run.9005]: Process exited with status 0
2012-12-02T05:46:26+00:00 heroku[run.9005]: State changed from up to complete
2012-12-02T05:46:35+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:setup` by jsabilla@ucsd.edu
2012-12-02T05:46:40+00:00 heroku[run.8128]: State changed from starting to up
2012-12-02T05:46:55+00:00 heroku[run.8128]: State changed from up to complete
2012-12-02T05:47:01+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:setup --trace` by jsabilla@ucsd.edu
2012-12-02T05:47:09+00:00 heroku[run.7343]: Awaiting client
2012-12-02T05:47:09+00:00 heroku[run.7343]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:setup --trace`
2012-12-02T05:47:10+00:00 heroku[run.7343]: State changed from starting to up
2012-12-02T05:47:25+00:00 heroku[run.7343]: Process exited with status 1
2012-12-02T05:47:25+00:00 heroku[run.7343]: State changed from up to complete
```

initially i thought it's because my db is empty i tried running: heroku run db:seed
and it gives me and undefined error nil class

any input would help at this point. thanks you

Answer (score 1):

Mongoid throws that exception when it's running on Ruby 1.9.2. You'll need to tell Heroku to use 1.9.3, just put this in your `Gemfile`:

```
ruby "1.9.3"
```